# Node.js FFMPEG Reporting Progress Architecture

Tags: node.js, ffmpeg

I'm running a node.js HTTP server which has a video conversion API built using ffmpeg. I am wondering how best to report on the progress of the file conversion to a separate front end. The HTTP server is going to be standalone as its own service, so I would like to be able to render the percentage complete of the conversion to another server with a simple front end. Upon completion of the conversion the file is downloaded automatically.

My current end point `/convert` takes a file URL with a .mov extension, downloads the file and runs it through the conversion process to only output Audio. Using response headers I force the browser to download the file once the conversion has ended, I also delete the temporary file once download has completed.

A full request would look like

```
https://www.someurl.com/convert?file=https://www.filetodownload.com/Skating.mov
```

I am using the fluent-ffmpeg npm package: https://github.com/fluent-ffmpeg/node-fluent-ffmpeg which serves a "progress" event:

```
ffmpeg('/path/to/file.avi')
  .on('progress', function(progress) {
    console.log('Processing: ' + progress.percent + '% done');
  });
```

I am thinking of emitting the progress.percent information on to a separate endpoint maybe along the lines of:

```
https://www.someurl.com/progress
```

Which will simply be my http server sending the percentage back to the browser. I feel as though I am going about the architecture incorrectly and there must be a better way of architecting the final outcome.

Comment: Depending on what browsers you need to support, consider websockets?

Comment: Would you suggest using websockets on both sides of this? e.g. to request the video to be converted and then to receive the percentage and final message to say its completed? Typically would I have 2 end points as per my post or is it best to handle it all over 1?